# Multiple Comment Moderators and Notifications

Tags: comments, notifications, moderation

I am looking for a way to make it so multiple authors/moderators within wordpress get notified when there is a new comment waiting approval.

I'm thinking of switching over to Disqus for this type of thing, but was wondering if it's possible without swapping out the commenting interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the plugin Comment Notifier.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comments-notifier/

And it works adequately.

Comment: *Bummer:*


`This plugin has been closed as of July 5, 2019 and is not available for download. Reason: Guideline Violation.`